# Gridlines splunk statistical table

Tags: dashboard, splunk, gridlines

I have splunk statistical table dashboard where I need gridlines for that table which is not available in splunk like in excel

Comment: Presuming this is on a Dashboard, you can change the CSS for the element to do what you want.

How do you want it to look?

Comment: Like tabular form with gridlines

Answer (score 0):

Presuming this is on a Dashboard, you can change the CSS for the element to do what you want.

In a hidden panel on the Dashboard, add some CSS styling - then connect the elements to their respective styles.

For example,

```
<panel>
    <html depends="$hideCSS$">
        #chooser .table th{
            font-size: 0ps !important;
            visibility: hidden !important;
        }
        #chooser .table td, .table a{
            text-align: center !important;
            border: 1px solid blue !important;
        }
    </html>
    <table id="chooser">
    ...
    </table>
</panel>
```

Comment: Thanks worked for me